# Break out of nested functions in a shell

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

If I have a series of nested functions, how can I break out of all of them from the innermost function?

EDIT: Busy looking into the builtin 'trap'...

Comment: Functions can't be nested in shell. There are no closures. Did you mean break out of all but the _outermost_ scope? Innermost doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ormaaj: All of them *from* the innermost function.

Comment: Ahh ok, gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

A rather ugly but easy way to achieve this would be defining STOP variable and checking it after every function call:

```
a ()
{
    echo a
    b; [[ "$STOP" == 1 ]] && return
    a; [[ "$STOP" == 1 ]] && return
}

b ()
{
    echo b
    c; [[ "$STOP" == 1 ]] && return
    b; [[ "$STOP" == 1 ]] && return
}

c ()
{
    echo c
    STOP=1; return
}

a
echo d
```

Not pretty, but it works in bash and zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a not-necessarily-portable hack that jumps out of all the required levels bypassing all `RETURN` traps, effectively prevents returning anything but 0, and is possibly a bug in at least some respects. This particular implementation is Bash-only but can be adapted to other shells.

```
function f {
    printf 'Current level: %d\n' ${n:+"$1"}
    if [[ $FUNCNAME != "${FUNCNAME[1]}" ]]; then
        [[ $1 == +([[:digit:]]) ]] || return 1
        typeset n=$1
        while ! f 1; do :; done
        unset -v n
    elif (( n - $1 )); then
        f $(($1 + 1))
    else
        trap 'printf "Returning from level: %d\n" ${n+"$1"}' RETURN
        # return # toggle
        break
    fi
}

f "${1:-5}"
```

output

```
Current level: 0
Current level: 1
Current level: 2
Current level: 3
Current level: 4
Current level: 5
Returning from level: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be done in the "classic" (C-like error-handling) way, i.e.:

1. Returning from functions with a status code.
2. Checking for status codes after every function call and doing accordingly.

And if we just need non-zero status codes (a.k.a. errors),
we can use `|| command`
instead of `if [ $? != 0 ]; then command; fi`
to make it short and clean:

```
    f1(){
        f2(){
            if [ "${things_went_wrong}" == y ]; then echo "Sorry!"; return 1; fi
        }
        f2 some arguments || return 1
    }
f1 some arguments || return 1
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I went with storing all the logic in a separate shell script instead of using functions. Exit will break out of the script entirely and allow your wrapper script to continue execution.